# Cannot overgive the user parameter to req.user in jwt.verify function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt

I am currently writing a jwtVerify.ts. It is the first time I am using TypeScript. Vs-code underlines the req.user and tells me that error:

> The type "undefined" cannot be assigned to the type object".ts(2322).

I tried now to check it like this:

```
if(user !== undefined){
           req.user = user;
            }
```

But then it tells me:

> The type string cannot be assigned to type "my user object" (2322).

I tried in my index.d.ts to define user with any, but then I have errors in all jwt functions. I tried to define user in the function as object but that gives back:

> No overload matches this call.

The code is the following:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
export const verifyToken = (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction)=>{
    const sec:string = process.env.JWT_SEC as string;
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;
    if(authHeader){
        const token = (authHeader as string).split(' ')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, sec, (err, user)=>{
            if(err){
                res.status(403).json('Token is not valid');
            }
           req.user = user;
            next();
        })
    } else{
        return res.status(401).json('You are not authorized');
    }
};
```

I have a @types folder with a file index.d.ts, in which I globally define an interface for Request user:

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user:{
                id:string!;
                vorname:string!;
                nachname:string!;
                username:string!;
                email:string!;
                street:string!;
                number:string!;
                plz:number!;
                city:string!;
                password:string!;
                isAdmin:boolean!;
                createdAt: Date!;
                updatedAt: Date!;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Request interface works. When I hover the "user" of req.user then vs-code shows me the content. When I hover the user parameter in my function, vs-code tells me, that it is "string | jwt.JwtPayload | undefined". So how I can define user in a way that TypeScript accepts this value? Without typeScript this function works. I used it before in my Mern-Stack exam.

I add my model, perhaps here is something wrong:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface UserDocument extends mongoose.Document{
    vorname:string;
    nachname:string;
    username:string;
    email:string;
    street:string;
    number:string;
    plz:number;
    city:string;
    password:string;
    isAdmin:boolean;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    _doc?: any;
  }
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema<UserDocument>({
    vorname:{type:String, required:true},
    nachname:{type:String, required:true},
    username:{type:String, required:true },
    email:{type:String, required:true },
    street:{type:String, required:true },
    number:{type:String, required:true },
    plz:{type:Number, required:true },
    city:{type:String, required:true },
    password:{type:String, required:true },
    isAdmin:{type:Boolean, default:false},
}, 
    {timestamps:true}
)

const User = mongoose.model<UserDocument>('User', UserSchema);

export default User;
```

I don't have id in the model because Mongo sets it automatically. I have _doc in the interface, because of the following function:

```
let sec:string = process.env.JWT_SEC as string;

const accessToken = jwt.sign(
            {id: user!._id,
             isAdmin:user!.isAdmin,
            },
            sec,
            {expiresIn:"30d"}
        )
        const {password, ...others} = user?._doc;
        response.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});
```

Without _doc in the interface, it throws me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I have written some code that works. Thanks to Neeray Kumar, his answer helped. Thats the code:

```
export interface UserDocument extends mongoose.Document{
    vorname:string;
    nachname:string;
    username:string;
    email:string;
    street:string;
    number:string;
    plz:number;
    city:string;
    password:string;
    isAdmin:boolean;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    _doc?: any;
    organization: Types.ObjectId; //This I found in the mongoose documentation. 
  }
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema<UserDocument>({
    vorname:{type:String, required:true},
    nachname:{type:String, required:true},
    username:{type:String, required:true },
    email:{type:String, required:true },
    street:{type:String, required:true },
    number:{type:String, required:true },
    plz:{type:Number, required:true },
    city:{type:String, required:true },
    password:{type:String, required:true },
    isAdmin:{type:Boolean, default:false},
    organization: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization' } //organization out of mongoose documentation
}, 
    {timestamps:true}
)
```

And that is the jwt.verify:

```
export const verifyToken = (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction)=>{
    const sec:string = process.env.JWT_SEC as string;
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;
    console.log(authHeader);
    if(authHeader){
        const token = (authHeader as string).split(' ')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, sec, async (err, user)=>{
            if(err){
                res.status(403).json('Token not valid');
            }
            if(!user) return res.status(400).json({error:"Not authorized"})
            console.log(user, req.user);
            if(user){
               req.user = <any>user; //that is the way to overgive user
            }
            next();
        })
    } else{
        return res.status(401).json('Not authorized');
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you

Answer (score 2):

You need to create **global.d.ts** file to explicitly add typing in any object.

Create **global.d.ts** file in the root directory. Write the following code in this file.

```
import 'express-serve-static-core'
    
export interface User {
  id:string!;
  vorname:string!;
  nachname:string!;
  username:string!;
  email:string!;
  street:string!;
  number:string!;
  plz:number!;
  city:string!;
  password:string!;
  isAdmin:boolean!;
  createdAt: Date!;
  updatedAt: Date!;
}

declare module 'express' {
  export interface Request {
    user?: User
  }
}
```

In tsconfig.json file
do this

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
     // Other options
     "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
   },
   "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
   files: ["global.d.ts"]
}
```

Find the user using Mongoose Model then save it in req.user object.
In your **jwtVerify.ts** do this

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { User } from 'usermodelpath'
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export const verifyToken = (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction)=>{
    const sec:string = process.env.JWT_SEC as string;
    const authHeader = req.headers.token;
    if(authHeader){
        const token = (authHeader as string).split(' ')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, sec, async (err, decoded)=>{
            if(err){
                res.status(403).json('Token is not valid');
            }
           const user = await User.findOne({_id: decoded.id}).lean()
           if(!user) return res.status(400).json({error: 'Not Authorised!' })
           
           req.user = user;
           next();
        })
    } else{
        return res.status(401).json('You are not authorized');
    }
};
```

Comment: @Neeray Kumar Thanks for your response. I cannot find rest options in the tsconfig. Where I have to set this? I tried in compilerOptions and out of compilerOptions, but both gives error and I can only put the file in the backend folder.

Comment: You have to add this file in you root directory where you package.json and tsconfig.json file resides.

Comment: I have updated the tsconfig.json file, try using these options.

Comment: Done it like this, started my application, gets back: backend/middleware/jwtVerify.ts(13,12): error TS2322: Type 'string | JwtPayload' is not assignable to type 'User | undefined'.
[0]   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'User'.
[0] backend/middleware/jwtVerify.ts(23,12): error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
[0] backend/middleware/jwtVerify.ts(23,45): error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
[0] backend/middleware/jwtVerify.ts(33,12): error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

Comment: So it is the same as before. It knows User in req.user but not want to have req.user = user and also it not wants the other user requests like req.user.isAdmin and so on.

Comment: I think the problem lies in your user object. Looks like your user object is not equal to the User interface. Find the user using the database and then store it in req.user object.

Comment: I added my model, perhaps there is the error?

Comment: I have updated the answer and updated jwtVerify.ts file. Try to do that.